# get latitude and longitude of a place dbpedia

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I want to get the latitude and longitude of a place whose name I already know by

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?s a dbo:Place .
  ?s geo:lat ?lat .
  ?s geo:long ?long .
}
```

where the name of the place (`?s`) is something like Graves Park.
How would one go about implementing the same in Jena where the name of the place might vary?

Comment: PREFIX geo:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX asd:<http://dbpedia.org/page/>
SELECT ?lati ?longi 
WHERE {
    asd:Graves_Park geo:long ?lati.
    asd:Graves_Park geo:lat ?longi.
}
gets an empty result

Comment: [Section 3.  Denoting or Naming “things”](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h18-4) of “The DBpedia Dataset” says that “Each thing in the DBpedia data set is denoted by a de-referenceable IRI- or URI-based reference of the form http://dbpedia.org/resource/Name, where Name is derived from the URL of the source Wikipedia article.”  If you dereference, e.g., http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock , you get redirected to http://dbpedia.org/page/Mount_Monadnock . The `resource` is the actual thing, and the `page` is just a page that contains information about it.  If you scroll to the bottom …

Comment: … of the page, you'll see links for “Raw data in CSV | RDF (…) | OData (…) | Microdata (…) | JSON-LD”.  If you select one of the RDF formats, e.g., [N-Triples](http://dbpedia.org/data/Mount_Monadnock.ntriples), you'll see that all the data is still about the `resource`, not the page.  It's sort of like how a biography contains lots of information about a person;  the information in the biography (on the `page`) isn't _about_ the biography (the `page`), but is about the person (the `resource`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. yes that makes things a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jena's ARQ to execute queries against remote SPARQL endpoints.  The process is described in [ARQ — Querying Remote SPARQL Services](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/sparql-remote.html).

## Using ParameterizedSparqlStrings in SELECT queries

To do this for different places that you might not know until it is time to execute the query, you can use a [ParameterizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) to hold the query and then inject the value(s) once you have them.  Here's an example.  The query is the one you provided.  I put it into a ParameterizedSparqlString, and then used `setIri` to set `?s` to `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock`.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;

public class DBPediaQuery {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        final String dbpedia = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
        final ParameterizedSparqlString queryString
          = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
                    "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>"+
                    "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" +
                    "SELECT * WHERE {" +
                    "  ?s a dbo:Place ." +
                    "  ?s geo:lat ?lat ." +
                    "  ?s geo:long ?long ." +
                    "}" );
        queryString.setIri( "?s", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock");
        QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( dbpedia, queryString.toString() );
        ResultSet results = exec.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out( System.out, results );
    }
}
```

The results printed by this are:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| lat                                                 | long                                                 |
==============================================================================================================
| "42.8608"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> | "-72.1081"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Once you have the `ResultSet`, you can iterate through the rows of the solution and extract the values.  The values here are `Literal`s, and from a `Literal` you can extract the lexical form (the string value), or the value as the corresponding Java type (in the case of numbers, strings, booleans, &c.).  You could do the the following to print the latitude and longitude instead of using the `ResultSetFormatter`:

```java
while ( results.hasNext() ) {
  QuerySolution solution = results.next();
  Literal latitude = solution.getLiteral( "?lat" );
  Literal longitude = solution.getLiteral( "?long" );

  String sLat = latitude.getLexicalForm();
  String sLon = longitude.getLexicalForm();

  float fLat = latitude.getFloat();
  float fLon = longitude.getFloat();

  System.out.println( "Strings: " + sLat + "," + sLon );
  System.out.println( "Floats: " + fLat + "," + fLon );
}
```

The output after this change is:

```
Strings: 42.8608,-72.1081
Floats: 42.8608,-72.1081
```

## Using ParameterizedSparqlStrings in CONSTRUCT queries

Based some of the comments, it may also be useful to use [`CONSTRUCT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#construct) queries to save the results from each query, and to aggregate them into a larger model.  Here's code that uses a construct query to retrieve the latitude and longitude of Mount Monadnock and Mount Lafayette, and stores them in a single model.  (Here we're just using `CONSTRUCT WHERE {…}`, so the model that is returned is exactly the same as the part of the graph that matched.  You can get different results by using `CONSTRUCT {…} WHERE {…}`.)

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class DBPediaQuery {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    final String dbpedia = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    final ParameterizedSparqlString queryString
      = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
            "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>"+
            "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" +
            "CONSTRUCT WHERE {" +
            "  ?s a dbo:Place ." +
            "  ?s geo:lat ?lat ." +
            "  ?s geo:long ?long ." +
            "}" );
    Model allResults = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    for ( String mountain : new String[] { "Mount_Monadnock", "Mount_Lafayette" } ) {
      queryString.setIri( "?s", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/" + mountain );
      QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( dbpedia, queryString.toString() );
      Model results = exec.execConstruct();
      allResults.add( results );
    }
    allResults.setNsPrefix( "geo", "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" );
    allResults.setNsPrefix( "dbo", "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/" );
    allResults.setNsPrefix( "dbr", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/" );
    allResults.write( System.out, "N3" );
  }
}
```

The output shows triples from both queries:

```
@prefix dbr:     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> .
@prefix geo:     <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> .
@prefix dbo:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .

dbr:Mount_Lafayette
      a       dbo:Place ;
      geo:lat "44.1607"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> ;
      geo:long "-71.6444"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .

dbr:Mount_Monadnock
      a       dbo:Place ;
      geo:lat "42.8608"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> ;
      geo:long "-72.1081"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .
```

Comment: what would be an appropriate way to store it in an rdf triple store?
im looking at ways of building a triple store but cant get my head around it.. i read that the result set will have the value only for one iteration and after that it will be lost.

Comment: how would one go about say storing the latitude retrieved from the above query to a string?

Comment: @Kriss As to the second comment: I've updated the answer with an example of iterating through the solutions in the result set.

Comment: @Kriss: As to the first comment:  if you want to save the data that you're retrieving, you might use a `CONSTRUCT` query instead of a `SELECT` query, and add the resulting graph to a local model.  If this sounds like a suitable option, I can update the answer.

Comment: I updated with an example a CONSTRUCT query the results of which are aggregated into a single model.

Comment: Thanks a lot! thats exactly what i was looking for.. although i have one doubt.. i queries Im performing are for pages and not resources. when i try to do it this way for pages i get no output(my first comment has the query string). i have the solution now but could you tell me why that happens?

Comment: @Kriss I took a look and replied to that comment.