# SPARQL query against Portuguese dbpedia endpoint for dcterms:subject returns no results

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia, dublin-core

I tested that query:

```
SELECT ?comment WHERE {<http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Portugal> dcterms:subject ?comment}
```

at http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql and I get the correct result:

```
http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Categoria:Portugal
```

But I'm using Jena and when I try to do that query with Jena I get no results.
That's the way I'm doing the query with Jena:

```
private String getComment(String uri) {
          RDFNode node;
          String comment = "";

            final String QUERY = 
                    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
                    "PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject>\n" +
                    "SELECT ?comment WHERE {" +
                    "<" + uri + "> dcterms:subject ?comment." +
                    "}";

      final String ENDPOINT = "http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql";
      final ResultSet rs = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( ENDPOINT, QUERY ).execSelect();

                while( rs.hasNext() ) {
                       QuerySolution querySolution = rs.next();
                       node = querySolution.get("comment");
                       comment = node.toString();
                    }

                return comment;
      }
```

Is there anything wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You haven't shown how you're calling it.  What's the value of `uri` when you're calling it?

Comment: Oh, sorry! The value is: http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Portugal

Comment: I'm using it with http, as it is wrote in the first query above, it's because when I paste it here at the comments, it changes its form.

Comment: You can surround text with backticks (`\``) in the comment (and in posts) to make them code, rather than markdown text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `dcterms:` prefix has a typo

The `dcterms:` prefix is incorrect (it has `subject` at the end).  It should be

```
http://purl.org/dc/terms/
```

### Use ParameterizedSparqlStrings to avoid injection problems

Also, the way that you're splicing the `uri` parameter into the query is a bit brittle, and it's subject to injection attacks.  E.g., what would happen if `uri` were the following string?

```
> <>* <> . <http://example.org/secretData> ?anyProperty ?comment . #
```

You'd leak information about `http://example.org/secretData`, since `<> <>* <>` will always match, and then you'd bind `?comment` to all the values of any property of `http://example.org/secretData`.  There's an example of how to do this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739846/1281433) to [get latitude and longitude of a place dbpedia](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16737653/1281433).

Comment: Thank you so much! It's such a stupid thing, but you helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad to help.  You should consider using a [ParameterizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) instead of string concatenation though, for reasons I'm describing in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful example about ParameterizedSparqlStrings !!