# How to label special cases in RandomForestRegressor in sklearn in python

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a set of numerical features (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5) as follows for each user in my dataset.

```
       f1   f2  f3  f4  f5
user1  0.1  1.1  0 1.7  1
user2  1.1  0.3  1 1.3  3
user3  0.8  0.3  0 1.1  2
user4  1.5  1.2  1 0.8  3
user5  1.6  1.3  3 0.3  0
```

My target output is a prioritised user list. i.e. as shown in the example below.

```
       f1   f2  f3  f4  f5  target_priority
user1  0.1  1.1  0 1.7  1       2
user2  1.1  0.3  1 1.3  3       1
user3  0.8  0.3  0 1.1  2       5
user4  1.5  1.2  1 0.8  3       3
user5  1.6  1.3  3 0.3  0       4
```

I want to use these features in a way that reflect the priority of the user. Currently, I am using `sklearns`RandomForestRegressor` to perform this task.

However, I got my real dataset recently and it has some users with no priority label. That is because such users are not important to our company (more like general users).

Example (How real dataset looks like):

```
       f1   f2  f3  f4  f5  target_priority
user1  0.1  1.1  0 1.7  1       2
user2  1.1  0.3  1 1.3  3       2
user3  0.8  0.3  0 1.1  2       N/A
user4  1.5  1.2  1 0.8  3       N/A
user5  1.6  1.3  3 0.3  0       1
```

In such special cases (that does not have a `priority label`), is it good to give them a special symbol or a priority level that is much much lower than the existing priorities (e.g., `100000000000000000 priority`)? **How does such special cases are handled in RandomForestRegressor?**

I am happy to provide more details if needed?

Comment: In your dataset, how many % of samples are with label `N/A` ?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar About 50% of data

Comment: Then I would suggest you to make 2 models. First to predict if a sample is *Priority* or *Non-priority*. Then use the data with *Priority* label to predict the `target_priority`.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar you mean like using the same features first do a binary classification to decide `priority` and `non-priority` and then perform regression on `priority` list to decide the level of priority? :)

Comment: Yup. Or you have fewer data suppose 15-20% then you can use it as a different category.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Thanks a lot for the valuable thoughts. I checked all of the data from different branches and it looks like some branches hasve about 80-90% of `N?A` lable. Just wondering how to handle such situations. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much once again :)

Comment: 80-90% NA in the target label or does that also include values among the input feature?

Comment: Also is the priority varying in a fixed range i.e. it goes form 1-10 or is it variable meaning that it can vary infinitely?

Comment: @anand_v.singh Sorry for the delayed reply as I just checked stackoverflow. The 80-90% users that have the label `N/A` means that they do not have any priority label. Answering your second question, the priorities are from 1 to nearly 50-100 - Actually it depends on the branch data (However, it is not indefinitely). Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay if 80-90% don't need a priority, you should build a classifier that decides whether the priority needs to be assigned or not, since this would be a skewed class, I would recommend you to use Decision tree or Anomaly Detection as classifier, data points that require priority will be an anomaly, you can use Sklearn for these.

After deciding the objects that have to be assigned a priority, I will look into the distribution of the training data with respect to priorities, you said that priorities range from 1-100, so if you have at least 5,000 data points and each priority level has at least 35 examples, I would suggest Multi class classifier(SVC with rbf kernel is preferred) and confusion matrix for checking the accuracy of the matrix, if that doesn't work You will have to use a regressor on the data and then round the answer.

What I basically mean is that if the data is huge enough, and there is an even distribution among target label, go for Multiclass classification, if the data is not big enough go for a classifier, If you want code for any part of it, let me know.

**Edit for Code**

Ok so let's take it from the top, firstly either in your target the N.A. values are stored as `np.nan` or they are stored as symbols like `?` or straight up text like `N.A.` in all cases this will result in your target label being of type object, to check use `df[['target']].dtypes` if it says int or float, you can skip the first step, but if it says object, then we need to fix that first.

```
df.loc[df['Target'] == 'N.A.', 'Target'] = np.nan #np = Numpy `N.A.` can be any placeholder that is being used by tour dataset for N.A. values.
df[['target']] = df[['target']].astype(float)
```

Now let's move to part two, where you need to get the target for your classifier, to do that use

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Bool'] = df[['Target']] != np.nan
df1 =  pd.concat([df, df2], axis = 1)
df1.head() #Sanity check
```

This will update your dataframe by adding true whenever a priority was assigned, this column will be you target for your classifier. **Notice** using `df1` and not `df`, now drop the `Target` from `df1` as it is not important, for the first part. `df1.drop(['Target'], axis = 1, inplace = True)`

Now I am going to use random forest classification in this since Anomaly detection should be avoided till classes are skewed upto 98%, but you can look at it [here.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html)

Moving on, to build the random forest classifier

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2) #Note max depth is a hyper parameter and you will need to tune it.
clf.fit (df1.drop(['Bool'],axis=1),df1['Bool'])
```

To drop the rows where the output is false

```
df1 = df1[df['Bool'] == True]
```

Then just use `clf.predict()` on the new data. Drop the rows where the output comes as false and run a regressor on the remaining data. I am assuming you can do the regressor part as that is now completely straight forward. Let me know if you face any further issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. It would be really great if you could show me how to do this part `Decision tree or Anomaly Detection as classifier` as I have not worked with skewed data before. Other sections I am clear how to do them. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: thank you so much. It would be really great if you could update the answer with that part of code. I am not in hurry. Friday is fine with me. :)

Comment: thanks a lot. this is very helpful. Yes, I am familier with the regressor part :) Just a quick question. When I did some reading I came accross two concepts named as `undersampling` and `oversampling`. When using `randomforestclassifier` does `undersampling/oversampling` happens automatically? Thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: @Emi no It does not happen automatically, but `randomforestclassifier` calculates feature importance in each decision tree and overall feature importance which reduces the need of balancing the dataset using under/over sampling. P.S.: I won't recommend oversampling/Undersampling unless it's the last resort because even the majority class would also be found in some very specific cases that might get removed :)